# E319: No "python3" provider found. How can I solve this problem on SSH environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, neovim

I am using university SSH, and I am trying to use Neovim.

However, it keeps saying that `E319: No "python3" provider found.` whenever I am trying to edit my code using Neovim.

I am not a sudoer.

How can I handle this problem?

I've tried `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim`, however, it says that module pip is not installed in `/usr/bin/python3` directory.

Answer (score 15):

In my case for the Neovim helps this:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim
```

Comment: this worked for me, when i started nvim today python3 provider not found, but checking it's version with `python3 --version` works

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to install python modules, and using sudo to pip install things is NOT recommended.

However, sometimes there are packages that are maintained by the community.  I would try: `apt install python3-neovim`

This should put the neovim python module in the place that neovim is expecting, as opposed to using --user or using pipx

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pip3 install --user --upgrade neovim
```

also learn about [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I handle this problem?

While @voortuck provides one workaround, which may/may not work, depending on whether neovim's python bindings are in pypi, a more straightforward way is to [build your own neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim), provided you have the [prerequisites](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Building-Neovim#build-prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed similar issue when few Python 3 versions were installed.

Solution: install neovim for all Python 3 versions that raise an error when
executing command:

```
:checkhealth provider
```

inside neovim.

What I have done and it helps:

```
python3.10 -m pip install --user pynvim
python3.9 -m pip install --user pynvim
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, neovim was using `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

So instead of just doing

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade neovim
```

I needed to do

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 install --user --upgrade neovim
```